# Как вписать вывод локальной машины tail -n 53 /etc/bashrc в файл на удалённой машине

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, администрирование, fedora

в общее надо что бы файл на удалённом хосте  именно отредактировался а не перезаписался новым , в общем  дописать в него нижние 53 строки из файла в локальной машине.

Answer (score 3):

Подразумевая, что с правами всё в порядке, как-то так:

```
tail -n 53 /etc/bashrc | ssh 'cat >>/path/to/remote/file'
```